# Teradata - Parsing data using strtok function - identify bad data

Tags: sql, teradata, strtok, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I need help in identifying bad data(PERSON_NAME) from below select query due to which query is failing as it is not able to parse FIRST_NAME & LAST_NAME.

```
       SELECT 
       PERSON_NAME
       ,Trim(OReplace(PERSON_NAME,StrTok(PERSON_NAME,' ',1),'')) AS AGENT_LAST_NAME
       ,StrTok(PERSON_NAME,' ',1) AS  AGENT_FIRST_NAME
       FROM TABLENAME 
       WHERE CAST(RECORD_START_TS AS DATE) = '2022-11-01';

   *** Failure 6706 The string contains an untranslatable character.
```

Actual Output should look like below:

```
           PERSON_NAME                  AGENT_LAST_NAME           AGENT_FIRST_NAME
           Abraham Gomezfitzgerald      Gomezfitzgerald           Abraham
           Adam Tregoning               Tregoning                 Adam
           Ajiel Marino                 Marino                    Ajiel
           Alexander Ford III           Ford III                  Alexander
           Fernanda Garvey Hernandez    Garvey Hernandez          Fernanda
```

Comment: Have you tried `where TRANSLATE_CHK(PERSON_NAME USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN)<>0'?

Comment: I tried now and this is not working.

Comment: 'Not working' meaning 'it returns no rows' or 'gives me xxx error'?

Comment: I suspect PERSON_NAME is CHARACTER SET LATIN and it's an implicit translation to UNICODE that is throwing 6706. You could use LATIN_TO_UNICODE in TRANSLATE_CHK. Or use either `CHR(32)` or `TRANSLATE(' ' USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN)`  as the second argument to StrTok and OReplace to avoid the implicit translation. Or since LATIN_TO_UNICODE translation only fails for the "Substitution Character" you can replace that one character with another such as inverted question mark: `OTranslate(PERSON_NAME,CHR(26),CHR(191))`